# How can I get the value of an unbound column in a combo box?

Tags: ms-access

How can I get the value from an unbound column in a combo box into a VBA variable?

I've got a combo box called `cmbEmps` that has a Row Source that looks like this

```
ID   Name    Active
1    Bob     -1
2    Jim     -1
3    Jane    0
```

It's bound to a field on my form on column 1, and my column Widths have been set to 0";1";0" so that only the name is displayed.

What I'd really like to do, is when Jane is selected, find out out that the `Active` column (3) is 0.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Refer to the third column in your combo box.  Column numbering is zero-based.

```
YourVariable = Me.cmbEmps.Column(2)
```

Comment: Worth noting that the ".Column" bit appears to be case sensitive; it won't work (or at least didn't work for me) if written as ".column".